# How can I create components from markdown in Gatsby like a page?

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am learning Gatsby and trying to expand their tutorial, which leaves you with a blog-like site. Each post is generated from markdown files, queried with Graphql and processed via onCreateNode and createPages.

I'd like to create markdown files for author bios that can be included on these generated pages. Then if a bio changed, the markdown would be changed in one place, instead of manually changing each markdown file written by that author.

Is it possible to have a similar, generated workflow for components? Or could I pass the author's name/bio file name to a component that does a query and processes the resulting markdown?

**Edit:** As I've considered this, I don't see much benefit of a markdown for my bios vs a component. Would it be bad form to have a component AuthorBio for the format and several components like JohnDoeBio or JaneSmithBio that return an AuthorBio with some information passed in props to render for them? I am fairly certain I can reference these components from my markdown or let my template choose them based on frontmatter, though that might lead to a large switch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same thought process! This is how I solved it:

> BlogPostTemplate.jsx
>
> ```
> <Layout>
>   <ShortBio {...authorData} /> // show the author bio on top of the blog post
>   <div
>     className="blog-post"
>     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} // your markup as HTML
>   />
> </Layout>
> ```
>
> ShortBio.jsx
>
> ```
> export const ShortBio = ({ authorPic, authorName, datePublished, readingTime }) => {
>   const postInfo = `${readingTime} · ${datePublished}`;
>   return (
>     <AuthorDiv>
>       <ImageAvatars src={authorPic} alt={authorName} />
>
>       <TextStylesDiv>
>         <Typography>{author}</Typography>
>         <Typography>{shortBioText}</Typography>
>         <Typography>{postInfo}</Typography>
>       </TextStylesDiv>
>
>     </AuthorDiv>
>   );
> };
> ```
>
> GraphQL:
>
> ```
> export const blogQuery = graphql`
>   query ($slug: String!) {
>     blog: markdownRemark(fields: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
>       html
>       frontmatter {
>         title
>         date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
>         author
>       }
>       excerpt(pruneLength: 165)
>       fields {slug}
>       wordCount {
>         words
>       }
>     }
>   }
> `;
> ```

Use the power of Gatsby and GraphQL and determine the author by its metadata in the markup. Look at the GraphQL query: I have an author tag defined therefore I can dynamically set an author just in the markup of the blog post.

> Or could I pass the author's name/bio file name to a component that
>   does a query and processes the resulting markdown?

Yes, use an author tag in the frontmatter of your markdown.

```
---
title: Hello World
date: "2018-01-15"
author: "Solid Snake"
---
```

> Edit: As I've considered this, I don't see much benefit of a markdown
>   for my bios vs a component. Would it be bad form to have a component
>   AuthorBio for the format and several components like JohnDoeBio or
>   JaneSmithBio that return an AuthorBio with some information passed in
>   props to render for them? I am fairly certain I can reference these
>   components from my markdown or let my template choose them based on
>   frontmatter, though that might lead to a large switch...

Creating several static author components is fine if you can confidently state that the the amount of author stays small. Be pragmatic. Do it like you said.